# Array of Matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to do some matrix operations on an image in a loop and I want to store each resultant image matrix individually. But I am confused if it is possible in Matlab to declare and use a variable as an array  of matrices like in C (`int array[r][c][n]`). Please advice.

Comment: Sure it is.. have you considered reading the manual, yet (no offense, really)? --> search for "multidimensional arrays"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 3D matrices to store multiple grayscale images, or 4D matrices to store multiple colour images.   Here are a couple of examples, supposing that you're doing some processing in a `for` loop.

---

## Grayscale images

First you declare a 3D matrix where the first two dimensions are the rows and columns of any image you're processing.  You need to make sure that **all** of the images share the same rows and columns as MATLAB does not support uneven multi-dimensional matrices.  As such, supposing we have `N` images and we have `rows` and `cols` as the rows and columns of a single image defined.  I'm also going to assume that your images are stored in `uint8` format, but they can be `double` too.  Therefore:

```
results = uint8(zeros(rows,cols,N)); %// To store the images
%// Or do results = zeros(rows,cols,N); if double type
for idx = 1 : N
    %// Read in your image
    %//....
    %// Process the image
    %//....
    %// Store the image for further analysis
    results(:,:,idx) = ...; %// Place instruction here
end
```

To access the i<sup>th</sup> image, you would simply do:

```
im = results(:,:,i);
```

---

## Colour images

This is the same principle, but we have a 4D matrix instead.  I'm going to assume that you have a 3 channel colour image (i.e. RGB).  You just have to extend the above code into 4 dimensions.  As such:

```
results = uint8(zeros(rows,cols,3,N)); %// To store the images
%// Or do results = zeros(rows,cols,N); if double type
for idx = 1 : N
    %// Read in your image
    %//....
    %// Process the image
    %//....
    %// Store the image for further analysis
    results(:,:,:,idx) = ...; %// Place instruction here
end
```

To access the i<sup>th</sup> image, you would simply do:

```
im = results(:,:,:,i);
```

---

## Uneven sizes?

If you have a bunch of images that you are processing and they don't all share the same size, you could use `cell` arrays as an option.  You can think of these as containers that can store any data type you want in each element.  As such, we can do something like this instead:

```
results = cell(1,N); %// To store the images
for idx = 1 : N
    %// Read in your image
    %//....
    %// Process the image
    %//....
    %// Store the image for further analysis
    results{idx} = ...; %// Place instruction here
end
```

To access the i<sup>th</sup> image, you would simply do:

```
im = results{i};
```

Note the difference in accessing the cell array in comparison to a normal matrix.  You use  `{}` braces instead.  Using `()` is designed for indexing into the cell array and performing slicing (i.e. accessing a whole bunch of cells and copying them over into a new cell array).  If you want the **actual** image itself, use `{}`.

Comment: cell arrays are another option.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar - I added in some stuff about cell arrays.  Thanks